# Программа, имитирующая работу матричного принтера

Tags: graphics, любой-язык, принтер

Получил задание написать программу имитирующую работу матричного принтера.
Должно быть 2 режима:

1. Ввод какого-то символа и на экране должна отобразиться матрица этого символа;  Пример:[image: Пример окна программы]
2. Ввод строчек матрицы и отобразить на экране получившийся символ;
   Пример:[image: Пример окна программы]

Нужно выводить на экран матрицу 11*9.

Вопрос: на чем это проще и быстрее всего написать? JavaFX или Swing? Либо вообще WinForms и C# ? Опыта нет ни с чем вышеперечисленным. Вывод в консоль не подходит, нужно что-то похожее как на рисунках выше.

Сам немного знаком с Java, но программ с графическим интерфейсом не делал.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на ваш вопрос ("на чем это проще и быстрее всего написать?") -  достаточно любого языка с консолью.

Судя по ТЗ, вам надо всего лишь уметь преобразовывать символ или набор чисел в "матрицу символа" и выводить её псевдо-графикой (текстом) на экран или в консоль. Вам подойдет практически любой язык.

Пример матрицы символа E в консоли:

```
########
########
##
########
########
##
########
########
```

Как видите, никакой графической библиотеки тут не нужно.

Comment: Интересным выглядит обратный процесс - из введенной матрицы понять, что за символ введен.

Comment: @alexoander для этого нужно, чтобы ТС уточнил проблему и привел пример ввода

Comment: @alexoander матричный сканер? Сдается мне, что такой функции принтер не должен иметь.

Comment: Нет, консоль не подходит. Должно быть поле ввода, какая-то область куда бы выводилась матрица. Вводить нужно 9 цифр. Как в примере здесь http://www.aic-crimea.narod.ru/E-learn/PC/1/5-11-2.htm

Comment: @Ivan уточните ТЗ, каким именно образом ввод 9 цифр тождественен вводу матрицы? Ведь 9 цифр можно и в консоли ввести ;-)

Comment: @Kromster, хех, задание такое поставили, чтоб все было красиво :)

Comment: Каждая введенная цифра равна строчке матрицы в двоичном коде, где 1 - это точка символа, 0 - пусто. Таким образом нужно построчно точками формировать символ. Для удобства вводить числа в 10 коде(где-то в программе переводить их в 2 код)

Comment: @Ivan ваша задача, как начинающего специалиста, научиться формализовать понятие "красиво" в четкое ТЗ. Дополните свой вопрос всеми этими деталями. А также уточните почему не подходит ввод этих самых десятичных цифр через консоль.

Comment: @Kromster тут видимо нужна та самая "красота" по госту - чтобы было наглядно и можно было мышкой погладить. Ну и вводить по одной циферке в нужные для этого поля/инпуты/формы без порядка и чтобы большое окошко появлялось, если букву распознало =). Но я с вами согласен - в консоли будет хорошо работать и ничего кроме стандартного in/out тут не нужно

Comment: @Kromster, Добавил в вопрос картинки, как примерно должна выглядеть программа.

Comment: @Ivan отвечая на ваш вопрос ("на чем это проще и быстрее всего написать?") - по прежнему достаточно любого языка с консолью.